# Any way to convert icecast stats to an rss feed and how?

Tags: rss, icecast

Only found a site that does shoutcast but im not sure how to do it with icecast. If there is a site that can do it for free or a small bit of code that can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Icecast uses the immensely powerful libXSLT engine to transform the raw XML status data into various output formats.

When I was experimenting with this XSLT engine in Icecast 15 years ago I wrote several output generators. One of them [generates RSS](http://ruecker.fi/foss/icecast/xslt/rss.xsl) output based on current status. By glancing at it I'd say that it's functional but could use some work to increase compatibility and such.

Please note that RSS is not really well suited for this type of data *and* that Icecast in its current version (2.4.x) does not provide *historic* data. That functionality is part of upcoming Icecast 2.5. This means that the RSS output only contains *current* data for each of the mountpoints.

If you are looking for the metadata history of each mount, you might want to look at the [playlist.log functionality](https://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/config-file.html#log) of Icecast or a STATS consumer.